# Sql Query Puzzling

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

My SQL Query errors stating:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

> BELOW is the query that doesn't work, but as soon as I replace
>   "Select" with "Select top 100" on the inner query (OQry), it works
>   (this is marked in the comments of the code).  The error looks to be
>   inappropriate.  Any ideas?:

```
Select distinct OQry.Create_tstamp, OQry.LDC_Account_Num, OQry.Territory_code, Replace(LEFT(OQry.Customer_Name,CHARINDEX(' ',OQry.Customer_Name)-1),'-','') as LastName, 
trim(Replace(Right(OQry.Customer_Name, Len(OQry.Customer_Name) - Len(Replace(LEFT(OQry.Customer_Name,CHARINDEX(' ',OQry.Customer_Name)-1),'-','') )),'-','')) as FirstName,
OQry.Commodity,OQry.confirmed_start_date,OQry.confirmed_drop_date,OQry.Market_status_desc,OQry.Reason_code,OQry.Flow_direction_Desc,OQry.AGENT_CODE,Da.AGENT_CODE as [Sub Agent]
from
(
select --This doesn't work but If I replace this with "Select top 100" then it works....  WHAT?!
d.Create_tstamp, d.customer_tkn,
right('00000000'+d.customer_tkn,8) + '-' + right('00'+d.customer_acct_tkn,2) + '-' +  right('0000'+d.account_pkg_tkn,4) as [Account Number], a.AGENT_CODE,
dl.LDC_Account_Num, d.Territory_code, Customer_Name, da.account_pkg_desc as Commodity, da.confirmed_start_date, da.confirmed_drop_date, d.Reason_code, d.Flow_direction_Desc,
d.Market_status_desc
from 
datamart_market_detail d
left outer join datamart_ldc dl on dl.Customer_Tkn = d.Customer_tkn 
and dl.Customer_Acct_Tkn = d.Customer_Acct_Tkn and dl.Account_Pkg_Tkn = d.Account_Pkg_Tkn
left join datamart_accounts da on d.Customer_tkn = da.customer_tkn and d.Customer_Acct_Tkn = da.customer_acct_tkn and d.Account_Pkg_Tkn = da.account_pkg_tkn
left outer join datamart_agent a on a.CUSTOMER_TKN = da.customer_tkn 
where Market_status_desc like '%Drop%'
) OQry
left join
datamart_agent Da
on OQry.customer_tkn = Da.customer_tkn and OQry.[Account Number] = (right('00000000'+da.customer_tkn,8) + '-' + right('00'+da.customer_acct_tkn,2) + '-' +  right('0000'+da.account_pkg_tkn,4))
```

Comment: no select top one million does the same problem, but select top 100 works.... hmm...

Comment: If it works with TOP 100 but not without it the issue is probably with your data. At a guess one of your Customer_Name fields is NULL, so CHARINDEX returns NULL and your LEFT statement then throws a wobbly.

Comment: oh!  wow, yeah that makes sense.  thanks for thinking about that.  Never would have thought of it....  I'll check it out.

Comment: The data will screw you up given the chance :-). Have a look at the link Eric has in his answer, it should make you think.

Answer (score 0):

You have a data problem, stemming from [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Somewhere in your data set, there's a value of `OQry.Customer_Name` that isn't structured the way you're expecting it to be in order for it to be the basis of a `CHARINDEX` function call.

Take a closer look at the data in that column.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM (...)  AS OQry
WHERE
  CHARINDEX(' ', OQry.Customer_Name) - 1 <= 0
```